# Closing skype does not pop it up in system tray on linux mint 12

Tags: skype, linux-mint

my x220 runs Linux Mint 12, Cinnamon (Ubuntu-11.10 based). When I close skype main window, skype process is still running:

```
$ ps -e | grep skype
 2327 ?        00:25:36 skype
 3828 ?        00:00:15 skype
 4342 ?        00:00:06 skype
 4426 ?        00:00:05 skype
```

No icon pops up in system tray. Last week I disabled system tray, because I don't like being notified by software updates... I read this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7505/skype-error-in-ubuntu-10-10 and added it once again in my cinnamon pannel. I killed all skype instances and tried to start it up again then close the main window. It does not show up in system tray.

Anyone having similar issue? Any solution?

Comment: (shamelessly answering my own question...)
After adding back system tray in cinnamon, I needed also to restart cinnamon. Now I have my skype icon. Sorry about the time waste..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(shamelessly answering my own question...)
After adding back system tray, I needed also to restart cinnamon. Now I have my skype icon. Sorry about the time waste.